# I am not able to check checkbox by selenium Web driver

Tags: checkbox, selenium-webdriver

[image][image]Please see the code given below and help me in finding Xpath. I am new to selenium.

```
<label class="checkbox">
<input class="chk-input" type="checkbox" data-bind="value: Value" value="3806">
<span data-bind="text: Text">GYM</span>
</label>
```

Comment: What code have you tried and what was the result?

Comment: I had used -->
WebElement checkbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='3806']"));
checkbox.click();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi to select check box please do it like below

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@value='3806']")).click();
```

**UPDATE**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (drv,20);
    // for location
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("location")));
    drv.findElement(By.xpath("location")).click();
    // for Position
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("Position")));
    drv.findElement(By.xpath("Position")).click();
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the early reply, but i was not able to check it because of the following error:

The given selector //[@value='3806'] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //[@value='3806'] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.
Command duration or timeout: 51 milliseconds

Comment: yeah at that point of time it was a typo error from my side ,i am sorry for that but now i have update the same u will not face the same error anymore

Comment: Requirements Change: At start Location and Position will be in hide mode, those will be populating when I select Facility as shown in first image. After selecting Facility then only Location & Position will be displayed as shown in image 2.        Now the code is not working. Any idea

Comment: yes you can easily do that first select facility it will be a normal task (as next two fields are dependent on facility -i guess ajax toolkit is used in your tool (if not no issues).now use ExpectedConditions with until i have updated my answer hope that helps you

Comment: Hey I have tried all the possible ways i can, but couldn't check it.  Can you provide me the solution. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To locate the checkbox element with an XPath expression, use the following format:

```
//tagName[@attribute='value']
```

- `//` indicates to search the entire DOM for the required element.
- `tagName` specifies what type of element you're looking for. For your example it would be `input`.
- `[@attribute='value']` is a predicate to only return elements who have an attribute equal to the specified value. For your example you could use `[@value='3806']` or `[@class='chk-input']`.

So pieced together, we can use the following as an XPath expression to find your checkbox:

`//input[@value='3806']` or `//input[@class='chk-input']`

Finally, to click the element you can simply use `WebElement.click()` like so:

```
WebElement checkbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='3806']"));
checkbox.click();
```

Comment: Requirements Change: At start Location and Position will be in hide mode, those will be populating when I select Facility as shown in first image. After selecting Facility then only Location & Position will be displayed as shown in image 2.        Now the code is not working. Any idea